# Use custom cursor instead of wait cursor (hourglasses) for WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

I use own cursor for my WinForms application; class looks like

```
public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Cursor _previousCursor;
    private static Cursor CursorResource
    {
        get
        {
            // get custom cursor from resources here
        }
    }

    private WaitCursor()
    {
        _previousCursor = Cursor.Current;
        Cursor.Current = CursorResource;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cursor.Current = _previousCursor;
    }
}
```

and now it works fine when I use it.

But are there a way to override system wait cursor with this one for entire application?

I found that it is possible to override system wait cursor using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hcur, uint id);
```

Are there the same trick for application-level only?

Comment: No, there is no such trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have not probed, but if you set the [Cursor.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current(v=vs.110).aspx) property and set the [Application.UseWaitCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.usewaitcursor(v=vs.110).aspx), then you'll get what you want.

Also, you can check this example:
http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/winforms/implementing-a-waitcursor-class